# Forcing a refresh on vuejs router from an outer app

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

This is as messy as it sounds...as it doesnt seem to be answered by other questions related to forcing a refresh in a vue app (but happy to be proven wrong).

I have a simple page utilizing some jquery which is loading a 3rd party vuejs app. The 3rd party app is loading correctly and working well.

The problem is if a link is clicked in the 3rd party app which is working through the vue-router. Although I see the url changing as per normal vue-router functionality but the view/template itself is not updating/changing.

If at that point I call a location.reload() then the page will reload and the correct template will display. However this is very slow and am trying to find out why the view is not refreshing under these conditions.
It obviously has something to do with the fact that I am generating the vueapp via external scripts but cant pin down what the issue is.

Is there some way I can force the view to refresh without reloading the whole page?

Thanks

Comment: Might just be a bug in the 3rd party app.  Can you post the code for its router?

Comment: its all minified so not really helpful. But the 3rd party app works fine in its source site. This is a process of pulling in the app from the site and displaying it in my own site (all legal and approved)

Comment: The question is if there is any way to externally force a view/template refresh without a page reload

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was something else going on here.

After the external vue app was loaded, some innerhtml content was being modified by my external script. Nothing directly related to the app but this seemingly broke the underlying app.

Stopping to do the replacements has the underlying app working as expected.